# Unexpected output from html form input DOM reference

Tags: php, html, forms, dom, xmlhttprequest

No matter what radio buttons I select, the console output is always "bcdab", even if I select nothing.

What am I doing wrong? Why doesn't my selection work?

```
<form name="quiz">
  <input type="radio" name="1" value="a"/>
  <input type="radio" name="1" value="b"/>
  <input type="radio" name="1" value="c"/>
  <input type="radio" name="1" value="d"/> <br/>
  ...
  <input type="radio" name="5" value="a"/> 
  <input type="radio" name="5" value="b"/> 
  <input type="radio" name="5" value="c"/> 
  <input type="radio" name="5" value="d"/> <br/>
  <button type="button" onclick="gradeQuiz();">Submit Quiz</button>
</form>

<script>
  function gradeQuiz(){
    var xhr=new XMLHttpRequest();
    var q=document.forms[0].elements;
    ...
    xhr.send("&1="+q['1'].value+
             "&2="+q['2'].value+
             "&3="+q['3'].value+
             "&4="+q['4'].value+
             "&5="+q['5'].value);
    ...
    console.log(xhr.ResponseText);
  }
</script>

<?php
  $choices=array($_POST['1'],$_POST['2'],$_POST['3'],$_POST['4'],$_POST['5']);
  echo(implode($choices));
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the problem:-

```
xhr.send("&1="+q['1'].value+
             "&2="+q['2'].value+
             "&3="+q['3'].value+
             "&4="+q['4'].value+
             "&5="+q['5'].value);
```

When you use `q['1']` - it calls second `<input>` that value is `b`
Then:-

```
q['2'].value= 'c';
q['3'].value= 'd';
q['4'].value= 'a';
q['5'].value= 'b';
```

So finally you got values `bcdab`

**Solution**:-

```
function gradeQuiz(){
var xhr=new XMLHttpRequest();
for (i=0;i<document.getElementsByName('1').length;i++) { if(document.getElementsByName('1')[i].checked){ val1= document.getElementsByName('1')[i].value; } }
for (i=0;i<document.getElementsByName('2').length;i++) { if(document.getElementsByName('2')[i].checked){ val2= document.getElementsByName('2')[i].value; } }
for (i=0;i<document.getElementsByName('3').length;i++) { if(document.getElementsByName('3')[i].checked){ val3= document.getElementsByName('3')[i].value; } }
for (i=0;i<document.getElementsByName('4').length;i++) { if(document.getElementsByName('4')[i].checked){ val4= document.getElementsByName('4')[i].value; } }
for (i=0;i<document.getElementsByName('5').length;i++) { if(document.getElementsByName('5')[i].checked){ val5= document.getElementsByName('5')[i].value; } }
...
 }
```

***And Finally***:-

```
xhr.send("&1="+val1+
"&2="+val2+
"&3="+val3+
"&4="+val4+
"&5="+val5);
```

Comment: I was under the impression that `form[0]` get inputByIndex where `form['1']` gets inputByName. No?
[source:MDN webdocs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/elements)

Comment: `form[0]` & `form['0']` both works same and both selects 1st form element where `form[0].elements` & `form['0'].elements` both get `inputByIndex`

Answer (score 1):

One more easy way:-

```
var q1 = document.querySelector('input[name = "1"]:checked');
var q2 = document.querySelector('input[name = "2"]:checked');
var q3 = document.querySelector('input[name = "3"]:checked');
var q4 = document.querySelector('input[name = "4"]:checked');
var q5 = document.querySelector('input[name = "5"]:checked');
```

***Finally***:-

```
xhr.send(
"&1="+q1.value+
"&2="+q2.value+
"&3="+q3.value+
"&4="+q4.value+
"&5="+q5.value
);
```